# Lie algebras over commutative ring

Tags: lie-algebras

What features will be  different when we define a Lie algebras over a field and when we consider a Lie algebras over commutative ring?

Comment: This is a rather broad question.  Are there some particular features you are interested in?

Comment: I want to investigate the Groebner-Shirshov basis of Lie algebras.

Comment: Well, they don't work, since Lie Algebras do not have to be free as modules.